# My script doesn't work in the server

Tags: php

I've written a script. It works on the local server, and I've loaded it in my site server. But It doesn't work there. And it gave out a white page. So I used this code;

`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

But it didn't gave out anything again. What is the problem?

Comment: Try to wear something red.

Comment: Maybe your server has gremlins that are eating the page before it is sent. Server gremlins can be pesky little things.

Comment: White page = definitely syntax error. eg: extra symbol in the wrong place, typing errors for commands, missing symbols like a semicolon... Look for these things in your code. At least, paste the code in the question (if it's a small one)

Comment: Maybe you have online some elder version than locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

is now so look for the error and correct

Comment: It's `display_startup_errors`, not `display_startup_erros`

Comment: I tried all of them. But it doesnt work. The site gives out a white page. Ive controlled the syntax errors. I couldnt find any error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's PHP manual - How to change configuration settings:
http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Some settings can be changed from your code, some from .htaccess, some from apache virtualhost, and some may be changed only in php.ini config file.